# htaccess redirect root to directory if directory doesn't exist

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, directory

using the htacces I want to redirect my url to a directory, which I am using this for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^dir1/(.*) /dir1/$1
```

It works great for scrips but not for images.

I was also wondering if there is a way to only rewrite if a directory doesn't exists in the root.

example:
mysite.com redirects to: mysite.com/dir1

but mysite.com/dir2 doesn't redirect if dir2 exists in the root.

I know its a little confusing. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use for that:

```
# Redirect if root folder doesnt exist (request_uri must begin with a dir (contain slash or contains only alphanum plus -))
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)(/(.*))?$ /dir1/$0 [NC,L]
```